Does logic "come before" mathematics, or vice versa?
I always thought of mathematics as being founded on logic. After all, even the most basic mathematical definition is based on logic. When we enunciate ZFC axioms, we're relying on the concepts of "axiom" and "axiomatic system", which are concepts of logic.
However, I've seen sometimes logical systems founded upon mathematics (see cathegorical logic). I always see mathematical tools used to prove statements about logical systems which, according to my previous (and clearly wrong) understanding are what mathematics is founded upon (the most trivial example being using mathematical induction over a set of propositions).
I understand that my question is quite vague, but I'm really no expert in logic, so as a beginner I'm very lost right now. My request is, can someone enlighten me about this issue I'm having, by clarifying the relationship between logic and mathematics?

Maybe ask about this on Philosophy StackExchange?  They seem to like this sort of question over there.

Define "coming before" please. Math and logic go hand in hand

The definition of a category gives you axioms that you can then work with, I don't understand the difference you make between logic and mathematics.

If you haven't read it, I'd recommend Thurston's essay On Proof and Progress in Mathematics, which explains that mathematical thinking is not purely about formal logical deduction rules, but also the heuristics and intuitions and analogies and understanding that one develops.

Relevant information: an identical question was posted by the same user on Philosophy SE in the same day. Why have you pasted identical questions without distinguishing what you expect from each community? Cross-posting is discouraged and disliked precisely for this reason. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/118268/does-logic-come-before-mathematics

The answer is basically yes and no. Mathematics can be founded upon logic, sure. But logic can also be founded upon mathematics. Basically, logic is powerful enough to model mathematics, and mathematics is powerful enough to model logic.
Historically speaking, both developed side-by-side for a long time, the origins of each are roughly contemporary in the West, logic being traced to Aristotle (though not without more ancient predecessors of course) and formal mathematics to Euclid (also with predecessors). Aristotle is probably slightly older of those two, however.

An example: in matelogic, an interpretation is a function. But, a function is a mathematical object. Does this mean you can't do metalogic without mathematics? In what sense, then, can mathematics be "founded upon logic"? At the same time, whenever you prove something in mathematics you use logical connectives. So it seems like "circular founding".

Yes, exactly. They're either both sensible or both not.

So, when you start building them, what do you start from? You have to start from some point.

In practice, no you actually don't. You build from some innate notion that logic and math both "work". Really, you have to start from some kind of innate notions that you can't prove, otherwise you'll never get beyond "I think therefore I am" and you might not even get that far.
